# Use Google Service Location in an Android plugin for Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-location-services

I am developing a Android plugin for Unity. I need to use the Google LocationService API, but it seems that Unity does not have the google services by default. I am missing the class "com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices".
 I've looked around on the web, but didn't find anything about location.

How do I use the Google Location API in an plugin for Unity ?